# Attempting to Push multiple entries to Firebase receive TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined for Firebase operation

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise

I have the following code in my React app that is adding entries to a Firebase table..

```
export const addMatchPredictionResults = (predsResultsData) => {

    const pushMatchPredictionResults = predsResultsData.forEach(pr => matchPredictionResultsFBRef.push(pr));

    return dispatch => {

        pushMatchPredictionResults.then(
             dispatch(deleteCompletedPredictions(predsResultsData))
        )
            .catch(
                error => dispatch(addMatchResultOrPredictionFail(error))
            )
    }
}
```

the pushing of the data to the table works as I can see the entries in Firebase. However I receive the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined'.

Does it anyone know what changes I need to make to get this to work. Doing a search on this error, it seems the issue is that I am not using the promise correctly. Is it because the code is declared as a constant and doesn't return anything?

Comment: You need to 1. compose an array of Promises 2. pass it to `Promise.all()` 3. call `.then` on the result. If that `push()` returns a Promise, you need `const pushMatchPredictionResults = Promise.all(predsResultsData.map(pr => matchPredictionResultsFBRef.push(pr)));`

Comment: I'm struggling. I did some more research and hacked my code and came up with ..export const addMatchPredictionResults = (predsResultsData) => {
    const pushMatchPredictionResults = new Promise(function(predsResultsData) {
        let promises = [];
        predsResultsData.forEach(pr => {
            promises.push(matchPredictionResultsFBRef.push(pr));
        })
        return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    return dispatch => {
        pushMatchPredictionResults.then(
           ...dispatch(deleteCompletedPredictions.. But results in predsResultsData.forEach is not a function.

Comment: That error isn't due to your changes; `predsResultsData` is the supposed array that you're passing to `addMatchPredictionResults()` elsewhere. The error says it's not an array. If you have updated your code, please put it in the question. As you can see, putting lots of code in a comment in unreadable.

Comment: My suggestion: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/p9wb2t76/

Comment: Thanks Chris. That has worked perfectly!